# Right click does not work in panel (firefox addon-sdk)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

i am creating a firefox addon using SDK and i was wondering why right click is not working inside the panel. Is there anyway to make it work ? or Is it meant to be in this form ?

Comment: It's not supposed to work there, but you can easily add support. I have to the research but add event listener on context menu and set id to the mainpopup menu I'll have to do a bit of research before i can supply an answer.

Comment: i want "inspect element" option to be shown in the context menu. Is that possible ?

Comment: Yes very easily. Check out this tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/PopupGuide/ContextMenus and this article helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/contextmenu?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMozilla_event_reference%2Fcontextmenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to Firefox 33, you don't get a context menu. From Firefox 33 you can enable a context menu by passing `contextMenu: true` to the panel's constructor e.g

```
var panel = Panel.Panel({
    width: 400,
    height: 500,
    contentURL: Data.get("html/view.html"),
    contextMenu: true
});
```